# i want the user to the able to select the quantity of products in this cart in angular

Tags: html, angularjs

Here is my simple shopping cart where I have list of products and when I click on each item I get details and I have add to cart button in the details page which adds the product to cart.

Immediate Help needed regarding this problem.
here is my link to plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/oo05d6H6AxuJGXBAUQvr?p=preview

I also want to provide user with the option of selecting the quantity of the product, the user can increase or decrease the quantity? can anyone suggest how I can implement this?

> **Script.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.controller('mobileController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    name: 'Iphone',
    price: 70000,
    rating: '*****',
    image: 'http://i.imgur.com/hfMaGTN.png'
  }, {
    name: 'Oneplus',
    price: 60000,
    rating: '****',
    image: 'http://i.imgur.com/sBcs5ZE.jpg'
  }, {
    name: 'Samsung',
    price: 50000,
    rating: '***',
    image: 'http://i.imgur.com/8Bexxbf.jpg'
  }, {
    name: 'Sony',
    price: 40000,
    rating: '***',
    image: 'http://i.imgur.com/0c7PcX8.png'
  }, {
    name: 'Moto',
    price: 20000,
    rating: '****',
    image: 'http://i.imgur.com/HyWR1VE.png'
  }];
});

app.service("cartService", [function(){

  var cart = [];

  function getCart(){
    console.log(cart);
    return cart;
  }

  function addToCart(item){
    cart.push(item);
    console.log(cart);
  }

  return {
    getCart: getCart,
    addToCart: addToCart
  };

}]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when("/store", {
templateUrl : "store.html",

 })

 .when('/item/:itemName', {
      templateUrl: 'details.html',
      controller: 'ItemCtrl'
    })
    .when("/cart", {
      templateUrl: 'cartdetails.html',
      controller: 'cartCtrl'
    })
    .when("/checkout", {
      templateUrl: 'checkout.html',
      controller: 'cartCtrl'
    });
});

app.controller('ItemCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'cartService',
  function($scope, $routeParams, cartService) {
    $scope.item = {};
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
      if (item.name == $routeParams.itemName) {
        $scope.item.itemName = item.name;
        $scope.item.itemPrice = item.price;
        $scope.item.itemRating = item.rating;
        $scope.item.itemImage = item.image;
      }
    });

    $scope.addProduct = function(item){
      console.log(item);
      cartService.addToCart(item);
       alert(item.itemName+" added successfully") ;
    };

  }
]);
app.controller('cartCtrl', ['$scope','cartService',
  function($scope,cartService) {
    $scope.name="sasiree";

    $scope.cartItems=cartService.getCart();

    $scope.getTotal = function(){
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.cartItems.length; i++){
        var item = $scope.cartItems[i];
        total += item.itemPrice ;
    }
    return total;
};



  }
]);
```

Comment: U mean clicking `add to cart` two times back to back of the same item? It is working fine for me. it is showing 2 products in the cart.

Comment: Looks like it's working now in plunkr.

Comment: yes it is working fine now as I have included track by index option! can you suggest how I can include quantity option for these products for the user to select quantity it should be like increasing or decreasing the quantity?